# Exporting an access DB to Excel through VB - with the first 10 rows of DB

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-access, vba

I am new to using VB alongside Excel and am in need of help.

I have an two access databases; one having 10 columns with many rows (more than 10), and the other Database has 8 columns and the same amount of rows as the other.

What I am trying to do is to export the first 10 rows of both databases to an excel sheet (in separate sheets or in two separate excel files, either way) so that this could be emailed or printed.

I've been looking around trying to get an idea on how to do this and have tried a few ways of doing it but none of them have worked.

Additionally I'll be fine if someone can help with exporting one database through VB with the first 10 rows of the database.

Could someone please help me.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: vb.net or excel-vba?  they are mutually exclusive.  `the first 10 rows of a database` means what?  oldest? newest?  how they are stored is not  usually relevant (or even known) to consumers of the data

Comment: Do you know enough SQL to write the query to generate the data you're looking for?

Comment: That's already generated, I'm simply taking the first 10 rows of the db (doesn't matter if you need to know if the data is ordered) (it is by lowest to highest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is something like an Import Data button in Excel, you probably want to use ADODB to connect to your access databases, select data into a recordset, then read the recordset into an array and assign to the worksheet you want to import to (optionally at the end of existing data - this depends on whether you're importing "10 more rows" or refreshing the top 10 rows (whatever that means - guessing you have a query to get these in Access, though).

Approach would look something like this. Oh, before we begin, you'll need to add a reference (Tools -> References) to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1`.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim strSQL_Query As String
    Dim oCN As ADODB.Connection
    Dim oCMD As ADODB.Command
    Dim oRecords As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strCN As String
    Dim strDBPath As String
    Dim varValues As Variant
    Dim wksTarget As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lngRows As Long
    Dim lngCols As Long


    '' Replace with the path to your DB. You could also use a dialog box to let the user choose a DB, if
    '' it moves around or isn't found.
    strDBPath = "C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb"
    strCN = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strDBPath & ";" & _
            "Persist Security Info=False;"

    '' Replace this with a query that does what you need it to
    strSQL_Query = "SELECT TOP 10 FROM [MyTable] WHERE <Conditions> ORDER BY [Column] DESC"

    Set oCN = New ADODB.Connection
    oCN.ConnectionString = strCN
    oCN.Open

    Set oCMD = New ADODB.Command
    oCMD.ActiveConnection = oCN
    oCMD.CommandText = strSQL_Query
    Set oRecords = oCMD.Execute

    If oRecords.BOF And Not oRecords.EOF Then
        varValues = oRecords.GetRows
        Set wksTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        '' You might need 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2 - I forget
        lngCols = UBound(varValues, 1)
        lngRows = UBound(varValues, 2)
        wksTarget.Range("A1", wksTarget.Range("A1").Offset(lngRows, lngCols)) = varValues
    End If

    '' Clean up...
    Set oRecords = Nothing
    Set oCMD = Nothing
    oCN.Close
    Set oCN = Nothing

    '' Do Some more stuff...

    '' And finish by saving the workbook
    '' 1) Check if the directory exists and create it
    Dim strDir as String
    strDir = "C:\Some\Path\Here"
    If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir(strDir)
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strDir & "YourWorkbookName.xlsm", 52 '' 52 is a constant indicating a macro enabled format
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx, the button I have that will run this code  update every time 10 rows from the Db - basically my db has at the mo 24 rows, all I need is to export the first 10 each time a button is clicked

Comment: Pleasure - so you can link the code above to a button in excel quite easily. You'll still need code to select the top 10 rows, and as @Plutonix said yesterday, that's a very malleable concept in DB terms. My suggestion is to create a query in Access that does what you want (use the UI if you're not comfortable with SQL), then change it to SQL mode and copy the SQL Access gives you into the string that houses the query. Same for the other DB you're connecting to.

Comment: Just wondering, where does this save the save the excel spreadsheet and is there a given name for it? Also how would I add column headers just above the data?

Comment: As it is, this doesn't save anything in Excel - it just copies the data into a range. You'd have to save stuff manually, or add `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Path\To\Your\Workbook.xlsx"` at the end. As to column headers, sorry, forgot about those. I believe there's an alternative method that brings them back, but failing that, what you can do it, before you pull out the data add something like `ForEach field In oRS.Fields : Range(A1).Value = field.Name : Next field`. You'd need to dim field, and I honestly can't remember if that approach gives you fields or values, or if `field.Name` is valid...

Comment: I'm having a few issues with the following - `Dim wksTarget As Excel.Worksheet` and `oRS = Nothing`. The first states that it is not defined and the second states that it is not declared.

Comment: ^Additionally `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Path\To\Your\Workbook.xlsx"` doesn't work either.

Comment: Right, sorry for that - wrote this when it was late, and didn't have a database to test against on hand. Edited the code - you'll note the changes:(1) Now uses `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` rather than `Excel.Woorksheets` (2) `oRS` is a standard name I use for my recordsets most of the time. I've used `oRecords` here though, so that gets set to nothing (3) Added the save code that works. Note the directory check beforehand.